# GitLab pull submodules inside CI

Tags: gitlab, git-submodules, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a GitLab project that utilises GitLab CI.
The project also uses submodules, both the project and it's submodules are under the same GitLab account.

Here is my `.gitmodules` file

```
[submodule "proto_contracts"]
    path = proto_contracts
    url = https://gitlab.com/areller/proto_contracts.git
```

I also have this piece in the .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
```

However, when i run the CI I get this error

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': No such device or address
```

Both the project and the submodules are in a private repository so you would expect to be prompted for authentication, but as I've mentioned, the project and the submodule are under the same account and one of the runner's jobs is to clone the original repository

[image]

So it's odd that it's unable to reach the submodule
Is there a way around it?

Comment: Can you add the relevant parts of your `.gitlab-ci.yml`?

Comment: @StefanvanGastel The only relevant part is the part where I set the `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY` variable, everything else is just building the code and running. I know for a fact that it fails at the cloning part (where it's supposed to recursively clone the submodules)

Comment: Do you have git clone ... in .gitlab-ci.yml? If yes, you should not

Comment: @ilia No, the gitlab runner is responsible for cloning, all I do is set the `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY` variable to `recursive` to make the cloning pull the submodules as well.

Comment: Could you post your .gitmodules file?

Comment: @ilia yes, I've just edited the post.

Comment: This answer might be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58019082/how-do-i-pass-credentials-to-pull-a-submodule-in-a-gitlab-ci-script/67843350#67843350

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You must use **relative URLs** for submodules. Update your `.gitmodules` as follow:

```
    [submodule "proto_contracts"]
        path = proto_contracts
        url = ../../areller/proto_contracts.git
```

Further reading: [Using Git submodules with GitLab CI | GitLab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/git_submodules.html)

Comment: Wow, I've somehow missed it while reading the documentation, thank you!

Comment: How do you avoid this interfering with development and deployment outside of gitlab?

Comment: Oh, never mind. That's something git understands. Awesome :)

Comment: I tried this and for me it did not make a difference.

Comment: Okay! But, if a have relative git path, then how could I work with submodules locally?

Comment: You can use relative paths in your `.gitmodules` file and it also will work locally. It's outlined in GitLab docs: When your submodule is on the same GitLab server, you should use relative URLs in your .gitmodules file. Then you can clone with HTTPS in all your CI/CD jobs. You can also use SSH for all your local checkouts (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html).

Comment: This does not take into consideration the possibility of using submodules outside of local instance and also repositories that require credentials.

Answer (score 2):

So things have changed a bit over at Gitlab over the years, but these instructions work for me as of now.

1. It's perfectly fine (and even encouraged) to use [absolute URLs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html) in your .gitmodules file.
2. Add the following to your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to configure the runner:

```
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
  GIT_SUBMODULE_FORCE_HTTPS: "true"
```

This tells Gitlab to convert any `git@gitlab.com/...` URLs to their `https://` equivalent and then automatically make use of the [CI_JOB_TOKEN](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html) to get access to the repository the submodule is in.

3. Runners don't automatically have access to other repositories. You need to go to the submodule repository and grant that access. Click the "Add project" you can see in the screenshot below, and enter the path to the repository that depends on the submodule.

[image: gitlab token access setup]

As long as the user who triggers the pipeline job has access to both the "main" and the submodule repository the runner should have all the access it needs now, and hopefully you should get a successful pipeline run! :).