# How to get gitlab-ci to checkout my submodule?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to configure an automated build in Gitlab CI.

My project has a git submodule.

I am using a Linux docker container runner.

Gitlab fails to checkout the submodule.

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file.

```
stages:
 - build
 
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

build-backend:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
  stage: build
  script:
    - dotnet publish MyWebApp /p:PublishProfile="MyPublishProfile" /p:Password=1234
  artifacts:
    name: "${CI_JOB_NAME}_${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}"
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - MyWebApp/bin/Release
```

Here the .gitmodules file

```
[submodule "MyWebApp/client"]
    path = MyWebApp/client
    url = git@git.mycompany.abc:company/client/myclient.git
    branch = qa
```

The error message contains this line

```
error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
```

Entire error message in gitlab

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.1.0 (6214287e)
  on runner-docker-builder-5.dev.nsynd.com t8cc1Yme
section_start:1596467453:prepare_executor
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 ...
Pulling docker image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 ...
Using docker image sha256:abc123 for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 ...
section_end:1596467453:prepare_executor
section_start:1596467453:prepare_script
Preparing environment
Running on runner-t8cc1yme-project-440-concurrent-0 via runner-docker-builder-5.dev.nsynd.com...
section_end:1596467456:prepare_script
section_start:1596467456:get_sources
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/company/client/MyWebApp/.git/
Checking out 0a9dd30c as qa...
Updating/initializing submodules recursively...
Synchronizing submodule url for 'MyWebApp/client'
Cloning into '/builds/company/client/MyWebApp/client'...
error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
fatal: clone of 'git@git.mycompany.abc:company/client/myclient.git' into submodule path '/builds/company/client/MyWebApp/client' failed
Failed to clone 'MyWebApp/client'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/builds/company/client/MyWebApp/client'...
error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
fatal: clone of 'git@git.mycompany.abc:company/client/myclient.git' into submodule path '/builds/company/client/MyWebApp/client' failed
Failed to clone 'MyWebApp/client' a second time, aborting
section_end:1596467459:get_sources
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

In both the parent project (MyWebApp) and in the submodule (MyWebApp/client) I have configured no deploy keys no deploy tokens.

Comment: This answer might be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58019082/how-do-i-pass-credentials-to-pull-a-submodule-in-a-gitlab-ci-script/67843350#67843350

Answer (score -2):

A Git clone will not automatically clone the submodule. You need to do an explicit [Git init and update](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-clone-a-git-repository-with-submodules-init-and-update) to bring the submodule code in.

```
git clone https://github.com/cameronmcnz/surface.git
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

I'm not sure if you can work that into your YAML file for GitLab.

### Submodule versions

Note that the [Git init and update](https://youtu.be/i7lRIICGPts) will not give you the latest code for the submodule, but instead you will get the version/commit of the submodule that maps to the commit of the parent Git repository.

Comment: You can use below to update the submodule with the latest commit:

`git submodule update --remote --recursive`

Add --recursive in case you have multiple submodules.

Comment: The question already included the use of `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY`, so I don't think this is relevant.