# Nested Git Submodules Failing to Recurse in Pipeline

Tags: gitlab, git-submodules, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a nested project structure such that there is a submodule within one of my submodules. The project structure is like this:

```
project A
   |_project B
   |_project C
        |_project D
```

Where A is a superproject, B and C are submodules of A, and D is a submodule of C. Project's C's file structure does not put project D at the top level of the directory, though this isn't a problem when I clone and update recursively manually. The problem I am encountering occurs only for project D, and only on my gitlab runner. Specifically, when the pipeline runs, it fails to instantiate project D with the following error:

> fatal: could not read Username for 'the-gitlab-server': No such device or address

Eventually leading to:

> Failed to recurse into submodule path 'Project C'

Projects B and C appear to instantiate correctly according to the job output. Something to do with the nesting appears to be affecting this, and only on the runner, but I cannot figure out what.

I have tried various configurations of .gitlab-ci.yml, both with variables and before_script. For example, in .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone
```

and on the triggering job I have instead tried:

```
<the-job-that-causes-the-failure>:
  stage: smoke
  script:
    - <job>
  before_script:
    - git submodule sync --recursive
    - git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Those exact commands correctly instantiate the completed project structure, including D, when I clone the directory personally and then run them, which makes me think the .gitmodules are fine for each project. Both the variables and before_script approach result in the same error.

The url field for each module is using a relative path as suggested in another answer elsewhere that did not resolve my problem.

The versions of git between the runner and my personal VM are the same (2.25).

Appreciate any help you can give; thanks!

Comment: Use relative submodule URLs as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48845464/gitlab-pull-submodules-inside-ci

Comment: Hi Gaël, my submodule URLs are already relative. I had found a similar post and made that correction earlier, but it did not fix the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, tried the same things and nothing.

I think I will remove recursive submodule strategy an add the inner submodules to the root .gitmodule.

But is a poor solution if works.

Comment: Unfortunately we did not find a solution; we had to do the same. Project B was a small project managed by us that was no longer being updated anyway so we incorporated it into A. Not an ideal solution, I agree.